# How to make PhpStorm interpret custom delimiters?

Tags: phpstorm, brackets, jetbrains-ide, ractivejs

I use Ractive templates in my Symfony application.

As my Ractive templates are in .twig files, I cannot use curly braces around my Ractive values, so I use Ractive's [custom delimiters](http://docs.ractivejs.org/0.8/mustaches#delimiters)

For example, `<p>{{text}}</p>` becomes `<p>[[text]]</p>`.

It works perfectly, but my problem is that PhpStorm doesn't recognize the brackets as template values, which causes several annoying consequences:

There is no syntax coloration, the indentation is messed up, and there are warnings where there shouldn't be.

**How can I make PhpStorm interpret my double brackets as template values ?**

---

Edit: example of code:

```
<script type="text">
    $(function () {
    var a = new Analytics();
    a.site = '{{ site.id }}'; {# Twig #}
    a.run();
});
</script>

{# Below is ractive #}
<table class="table">
    <tr class="general">
        <th></th>
        [[#each columns: i]]
            [[#if stats]]
                <th>[[trans('column.' + columns[i])]]</th>
            [[/if]]
        [[/each]]
    </tr>
    [[> totalLine]]
    [[#each templates: t]]
        [[> templateLine]]
    [[/each]]
</table>
```

Comment: So .. you have template inside template, right? "Normal" template processed by Twig on server side .. and then on client/browser inner template gets processed/used by another engine... It's all fine. Would be good to see such sample code though (a file that I can copy-paste in my test project and play with it a bit)

Comment: **1)** I just do not think that IDE supports such "template inside template" processing even if both templating engines are supported separately (via separate plugins: Twig & Handlebars/Mustache , for example). *I guess* because of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106449 **2)** Handlebars/Mustache plugin (for example) has no options page .. so you cannot configure what braces to use (same with Twig though; only Blade/Smarty have such customisation).

Comment: I guess, in addition to the aforementioned ticket (check related tickets as well) you will be interested in these: 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14385 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14336

Comment: Thanks a lot, and by the way I added a code example

Comment: What the file name (mainly extension) you are using -- something like `file.html.twig`?

Comment: Yep, file.ractive.twig. BTW, there is so few twig that I don't care about it, only ractive is important

Comment: BTW -- you do not have any separation of the templates -- I personally do not see how multiple templating syntaxes/engines can be injected here (from IDE side, of course) even if first mentioned by me ticket would be implemented (based on my knowledge of how this IDE works)...

Comment: Most of the time, it is separated, the twig in my example is a very rare case in my app (and I can easily get rid of it)

Comment: Not sure what to suggest. In any case (considering your example) -- maybe something like this will work for you (sorry, not tested myself if it's works or not -- just an idea -- need to check if including can be done as raw text without processing by Twig first)? https://postimg.org/image/qjqk50rzn/ (using Twig and Handlebars/Mustache plugins -- note the `{{ }}` on both files).

Comment: Other than that: 1) I still recommend to file a ticket to the Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI -- I also want to see what devs will say 2) See if devs of Handlebars/Mustache can implement support for custom delimiters . No other bright ideas right now

Answer (score 0):

This is one example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Your *real* problem (the "X problem") is Ractive syntax, specifically the `{{ }}`, is being treated as Twig by the parser. This can be solved by wrapping the Ractive template around a [`verbatim`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/verbatim.html) section to prevent Twig from treating that Ractive template like Twig.

The "Y problem" stems from your attempt to work around the "X problem". That is, IDE syntax highlighting when using custom delimiters.

Why the `{{ }}` syntax-highlighting on Ractive templates appear to work is because Twig has syntax that involves `{{ }}`. However, the highlighting knows nothing about Ractive at all. It just happens that both languages use `{{ }}` in a similar fashion that the syntax highlighter thinks it's Twig... and styles like Twig.

Also, most, if not all IDEs, only support single-language highlighting. Since your file is being treated as a Twig template, it gets Twig highlighting. Should multi-language syntax-highlighting be supported is determined by your IDEs vendor and there's nothing you can do about it (unless you make your own plugin of course).

Comment: Actually, the X problem is not really a problem, it's a fact : I use custom delimiters and I cannot change them because this is a big team project and not a personal project. I cannot "solve" the X problem.

However, I'm the only one using PhpStorm, which mean I'm the only one being concerned about my issue.

Concerning the multiple language highlighting, I actually don't care about it, as the twig and the ractive are 99% of the time in different files with different extensions (.html.twig and .ractive.twig). 

And as LazyOne suggested, I posted the issue on Jetbrains' issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question related to VueJS and Twig curly brackets.

The only solution I found is to autocomplete `[[` construction with tab button so it appears as `[[ _ ]]`.

[image]